# Materialize CSS autocomplete from XML

Tags: javascript, php, css, xml

I am trying to parse XML in PHP and then put it as an object in JavaScript to Materialize CSS autocomplete.

I tried to parse it in PHP and put it as an object in JavaScript with `json_encode($array)` But it didn't work. Autocomplete shows just numbers.

You have to put data as an object in "data". And it must be as `"string": 'http://url'` the URL is for a thumbnail. But I want it as `"string": null`. So there won't be a thumbnail.

This is a sample from Materialize CSS documentation: https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
    });
  });
```

My XML file:

```
<tittle>

<topic>
<name>PHP</name>
</topic>

<topic>
<name>JS</name>
</topic>

<topic>
<name>CSS</name>
</topic>

</tittle>
```

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>  
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



  <?php

  $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml");

  $array = array();

  foreach($xml->topic as $topic)
  {
    $array[] = $topic->name;  
  }

  ?>


    <script >
    var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
    console.log(array); 

  $(function () {
  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: array     

  });
});

</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

An output of `console.log(array);`:

[image]

The autocomplete is displaying just numbers (0-2). I think those numbers are array indexes.

I think I must change the array structure to `"string_from_array": null`

Is there any way how to do it? Thank you for response

Comment: You asked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738061/materialize-css-autocomplete-from-xml which is now deleted and your asking it again.

Comment: I know, I didn't ask well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change line

```
$array[] = $topic->name;
```

to

```
$array[$topic->name] = $topic->name;
```

that should solve your problem, but not best way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it isn't working. It says `Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\help\index.php on line 36.` And there is nothing in `console.log(array);`

Comment: `$array[$topic->name] = $topic->name;` -> `$array[(string)$topic->name] = (string)$topic->name;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($xml->topic as $topic)
   {
   $array[$topic->name] = null;  
   }
```

Comment: `$array[$topic->name] = null;` needs to be `$array[(string)$topic->name] = null;`

Comment: Why should one try that? Can you explain your answer such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

you can add array_flip function to put the values in the keys of the array. Change this line

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

so it becomes

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode(array_flip($array)); ?>;
```

Comment: It says: `Warning:  array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in C:\xampp\htdocs\help\index.php on line 43`. And it isn't working